# multiple instances of Singleton CGI Object in perl

Tags: perl, mod-perl

i hava a cgi page index.cgi and one template of login form as

index.cgi

```
use Singleton::CGI;
use Singleton::Session;

$q = new Singleton::CGI();
$session = new Singleton::Session();
$template = HTML::Template->new(filename => 'login.tmpl');

print $q->header;
print $q->start_html("hello perl");
print $q;   # printing hash of CGI Object.
print $session;
print $template->output;
print $q->end_html;


if($q->param('submit')){

print $q->header;
print $q->start_html("hello user");
print $q;   # printing hash of CGI Object.
print $session;
print $q->param('text');
print $q->end_html;

}
```

login.tmpl:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
```

here is the output when i get the index.cgi

CGI=HASH(0xbe0510)
SingletonSession=HASH(0x1e67ee60)

along with form

next when i submit the form then 
CGI=HASH(0xe2ac500)    alnog with form input value.
SingletonSession=HASH(0x115dc7a0)

as per my requirement i should only get one session Object.

how should i maintain only one query and session Object through out the application?

Answer (score 3):

Your web server executes your script for each request it receives, so you're asking to share a variable across two processes that aren't even running at the same time. Impossible. That's why sessions are used, to provide persistence of information.

Comment: yes i used session Object to persist the data .. with singlton Session Object . but getting multiple instances treating it as a new process.

Comment: Your comment is very hard to understand, but I think you've merely repeated what you already said. If that's the case, my answer is still the same. It's impossible to share *variables* across processes. It's possible to share *data*, but you didn't say or show anything about any data.

Comment: http://www.debian-administration.org/    when i see the source code of it , different forms have  actions has the url '/' which is the starting page. bui it doesnot creates the new cgi and session object for each time.how it is possible                                  here is the link of the source code                                                                      http://code.ohloh.net/project?pid=Gfmu7b-JvKI&prevcid=1&browser=Default&did=yawns.repository.steve.org.uk&cid=Njw0CcmpMfQ&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&filterChecked=true

Comment: If your question is incomplete, update the question. But before you do that, keep in mind that neither of those links have a demonstration of the problem.